# How to send signals from arduino to android using bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I need to know this as a part of my final project.

How can a signal send to an android smartphone from an arduino board using bluetooth?

I saw its very simple to sent signal from smartphone to arduino via bluetooth.

My question is how the inverse of this can be done????

Comment: Once you establish the connection, you can send information either way. Serial is easiest. If you want to use BLE, you got a bit more work to do. What's your hardware?

Answer (score 0):

> I saw its very simple to sent signal from smartphone to arduino via bluetooth.

What you probably do is a `Write operation` from the GATT Client on the smartphone to a Characteristic on the GATT Server on Arduino.

> My question is how the inverse of this can be done?

The "inverse" involves the GATT Server sending data to the Client. To do that, the Server must have a Characteristic which has the Notification property, and the Client must enable the Notification by writing the CCCD. Then, the Server will send data to the Client whenever it wants to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JArduino](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/JArduino)-Library  if you just want to send/receive signals from the Arduino board in Android.